# How can you tell when a website has updated its content without using headers?

Tags: javascript, http-headers

So a bit of background, I have a JavaScript library that customers install on their sites. The library uploads the page's content the first time it's loaded and stores certain words in our database. I want to know when the page has updated its content without having to re-upload the content with every request. Currently I am scanning the page again 24 hours later and if there are any changes updating the database.

I can't guarantee that our customers will be using the `304 If Modified Since` HTTP header otherwise I would have used that to check for a change in content.

Are there any other possible ways? I was thinking I could possibly compare the date the record in the database was created/updated at to `document.lastModified` but I've heard this is unreliable because for example pages generated by a CMS can have their `document.lastModified` date updated on each page load.

I really appreciate any help or ideas you have.

Thanks

Comment: You could store the contents in a url that's a sha1 of the payload, then fail (or just not make) the POST if it already exists. Once you start saying "I don't trust this client," you're going to be rolling things on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the response David, I can't say I really understand it though sorry as my technical knowledge doesn't go that far. I'll do a bit of reading and see if I can figure it out unless you can brake it down a bit more?